# temporal dead zone (ES6) doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, iife, traceur

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1 id="message"></h1>

<script src="traceur/traceur.js"></script>
<script src="traceur/BrowserSystem.js"></script>
<script src="traceur/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="module">

    var x = 'outer scope';
    (function() {
        console.log(x); //Expected undefined, got undefined ! this is as expected.
        var x = 'inner scope';
    }());

    //same as above, but changed to var to let and x to y
    let y = 'outer scope';
    (function() {
        console.log(y); //Was expecting ReferenceError here, but got undefined. WTF ??!!!
        let y = 'inner scope';
    }());


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Its seems the temporal drop zone (TDZ) in es6 should throw a referenceError in case the let-var is used before it is declared.

However, in this example, I am getting undefined for let.
Where am i going wrong?

Been at this problem for a long time and wasted a day on this. (Any pointers would be very help). I am using Chrome v58.

v58 has es6 compatibility as per https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ under current browser).

I stripped off the traceur part and posted on babel-try it out, and got the same result. [image]

Am wondering why is it not working in my chrome v58. Maybe it requires something else too??

Comment: FYI, it's called *temporal **dead** zone*, not temporal *drop* zone.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Traceur, which [does not support TDZ for let/const](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let_temporal_dead_zone). It will convert `let` to `var` - making the TDZ behaviour for let identical to your var example. Run the same code in an ES6-compatible environment and you'll see the expected result:

```js
var x = 'outer scope';
(function() {
    console.log(x);
    var x = 'inner scope';
}());

let y = 'outer scope';
(function() {
    console.log(y);
    let y = 'inner scope';
}());
```

Comment: what browser and its version are you using? I evaluated my Chrome v 58 and using kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6 (under current browser) and looks like it is ES6 compatible.

Comment: Chrome 58 also. Did you click on the *Run code snippet* button above? Should show the correct result below

Comment: Yes, i saw that. but wondering why it ain't working in my Chrome browser v 58. Tried it on babel try it out and I am getting same result. undefined. which is wrong

Comment: @Plankton Are you still including Traceur in your code? You need to remove that to see the behaviour. Babel doesn't support let/const TDZ either (outside of a flag)

Comment: Nope, i removed the traceur part (obviously). wait will attach a screenshot.

Comment: @Plankton You posted a screenshot of it in Babel. Like I said, it doesn't work in Babel. Try it in JSFiddle, Plunkr, or just in your console. Something that doesn't do transpilation

Comment: works on plunkr. yes. but i want to get it working on my chrome (if it works on ur chrome, it should work on mine too right?) . I found chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony  and the Experimental Jasvascript section was not enabled and i enabled it, but still no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145853/discussion-between-codingintrigue-and-plankton).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the transpiler code and enabled the Experimental Features in JS 
chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony here and it worked as expected now.

Chrome version v58